# Re-usable React components that modify parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just wanting to understand the best way to make re-usable react components that interact with the state of their parent component.

---

**Edit:** I have followed the helpful advice by [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1960327/peter-lazzarino) and made it more modular, but I still have an issue in updating the parent component state from the child.Do I have no choice but to pass it a method, and then have to repeat this method in all places that uses the `<Modal />` component?
**is this unavoidable?**
**[Updated codepen here](https://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/5c1a70b6951323f53b6c065b96a53202?editors=0010)**

---

I have a react component that needs to write to its parent state.
Using a `<Modal />` as an example, if the modal is shown, its parent component updates its state to `modal1 : ‘is-visible'`.
The is-visible is added as a class to the modal.

**The issue I have** is that I have 3 functions / methods that update the state and animate the modal and I need to copy these functions / methods to every component that uses the `<Modal />` component.

[codepen here](https://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/76b174b7fad49af0b5c61410f897ec0c?editors=0110)

**Is there anyway to get around this?**
Can these methods that talk to the parent component live inside the component itself?

That way I can just drop the modal component in viola, it works without repeated function methods around my application.

Modal:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      extraClasses: ''
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({ extraClasses: props.extraClasses });
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.props.closeModal();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={'c-modal ' + this.props.extraClasses}>
        <div className="c-modal__bg" onClick={this.closeModal}></div>
        <div className="c-modal__inner">
          <button className="c-modal__close-modal" onClick={this.closeModal}>X</button>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`<ParentComponent />` here, note the 3 function/methods:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    this.animateModal = this.animateModal.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      // modal1: '',
      // modal2: ''
    };
  }

  animateModal(type, stateProp) {
    if (type == 'show') {
      this.setState({ [stateProp]: 'c-modal--display-block' })
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ [stateProp]: 'is-visible' })
      }, 0);
    } else if (type == 'hide') {
      this.setState({ [stateProp]: 'c-modal--display-block' })
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ [stateProp]: '' })
      }, 300);
    }
  }

  showModal(modalNum) {
    this.animateModal('show', 'modal' + modalNum)
  }

  closeModal(modalNum) {
    this.animateModal('hide', 'modal' + modalNum)
  }

   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen ✨</h2>

         <button className="c-btn" onClick={() => this.showModal(1)}>show modal</button>
        <Modal extraClasses={'extraClassesHere ' + this.state.modal1} closeModal={() => this.closeModal('1')}>
          <h1>I'm a modal</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus fugit dicta quisquam est nihil vel, suscipit sit veritatis eum accusantium voluptas temporibus ut et, distinctio, illum assumenda sint libero voluptate.</p>
        </Modal>

      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The modals state should be *in* the modals state.

Comment: Thanks @JonasW. see this comment below - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943868/re-usable-react-components-that-modify-parent-state?noredirect=1#comment86907515_49943953

Answer (score 3):

If you moved the animate show and close methods into the modal component itself you could just have a prop for modal called isShown. When that isShown prop changes you could animate into its hidden or shown state. You could also provide onShown and onHidden callbacks which can fire after the animation is complete if you need some more control at the parent level.

Let me know if I'm not understanding correctly!

Comment: Thanks for the help! The problem with is that the parent component cannot be updated from the child. https://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/5c1a70b6951323f53b6c065b96a53202?editors=0010

The parent retains 'is-shown' state property after closing the modal.
image here - https://i.imgur.com/U6zWkcZ.png
this is a tricky one. Thanks very much for the help! 

Comment: Ah I see, I think in this case the parent should not care about the open or close state of the modal. Having only the modal care about its open or close state would help clean up the code a bit it seems.

Comment: Thanks Peter. 
codepen here - https://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/5d80648d971dcb6d360506bee6ec80ea
the issue I have I dont see how its possible to show or hide a child component, without interacting with the parent components state. Any ideas, or is this how it is?